# Why is my Node.js if else condition not recognized?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code

```
console.log('Starting app');

const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');
const _ = require('lodash');

const notes = require('./notes.js');

var command = process.argv[2];
console.log(command);


if (Comment = 'add') {
    console.log('adding new note');
  } else if (command = 'list') {
    console.log('listing all notes');
  } else {
    console.log('command not recognized');
  }
```

When I run

```
 node app.js list
```

I got

```
Starting app
Starting node.js
list
adding new note
```

What is wrong with my else if statement?

Comment: `Comment = 'add'` is not a comparison, it is an assignment. Its value is the value of `Comment` after the assignment (i.e. `'add'`) which is never false. Read about the [JavaScript operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)

Comment: `if (Comment = 'add')` -> `if (command == 'add')`

Comment: Node.js is not involved in this question.

Comment: Ok,it is from Node.js book,but javascipt syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=` is the assignment operator. You're **assigning** `'add'` to `Comment`, and then checking if this value evaluates to `true` in a boolean context, which it of course does. You should use the `===` operator:

```js
if (Comment === 'add') {
    // Here-^
```

Also `Comment` is not declared anywhere, which will result in `ReferenceError` and crash your process.

Comment: Downvoted for answering obvious duplicate.